# Returning a stream directly to the web browser

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, file-io, pagemethods

I am generating a file on the server and I do not want to write it to disk but instead return it to the client via a web service. What recommendations would you have to do this?

Comment: Do you mean a SOAP-like web service call or just a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.OutputStream.Write(...)
```

Or if you have a MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream ms = ...;
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

**Edit:**

If it's a SOAP web service, then just return a byte array from your web service method in your asmx.cs file

Comment: Do you know what I would do with the byte[] on the client side javascript?

Comment: What did you _want_ to do with it? What's in the file?

Comment: Yes, what would you do with a file received by JavaScript? You can't (reliably) embed an image in such a way if that's your bag. If it is an image, there are better options.

Comment: What PDF reader? If it's some Flash thing I suspect you would point it at a URL as opposed to load in a file manually. If it's an iframe again you should just load a URL! In which case you could use the first part of my answer.

Comment: You can't use a pagemethod for this purpose. You just want a handler (.ashx file). This would have a URL with params: http://s/p.ashx?file=x.pdf. User or page would just browse to that URL and It would then return the x.pdf file set to open in browser.